# Clips programming - comparing the value of global variables

Tags: global-variables, clips

I'm learning Clips programming and I encountered an issue. I'm trying to use an if-then-else statement and test if two global variables are equal. So far I have the following code:

```
(defglobal ?*count_x* = 0)
(defglobal ?*count_y* = 0)
(defrule if_then_else
    ?x <- (?*count_x*)
    ?y <- (?*count_y*)
   =>
   (if  (eq ?x ?y)
      then
      (printout t "Yes, they are equal. " crlf)
      else
      (printout t "No, they are not equal." crlf)
      (printout t "x: " ?*count_x* crlf)
      (printout t "y: " ?*count_y* crlf))
      (retract ?x)
      (retract ?y)
)
```

This is not all the code,the counters are increased fine, but this is the part that doesn't work fine. Is there a way to do this without replacing the global variables with defrules? Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind the globals in the conditions of the rule. Just reference them directly:

```
(defglobal ?*count_x* = 0)
(defglobal ?*count_y* = 0)
(defrule if_then_else
   =>
   (if  (eq ?*count_x* ?*count_y*)
      then
      (printout t "Yes, they are equal. " crlf)
      else
      (printout t "No, they are not equal." crlf)
      (printout t "x: " ?*count_x* crlf)
      (printout t "y: " ?*count_y* crlf))
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified but somehow it always prints the Yes part( I'm reading the input from keyboard and passing it from Python to Clips code). So if I enter 1,2,3 for count_x and 1,5,6,4 for count_y it prints Yes because the first value is equal. How can I test after all the counting has been done? Tried salience but no difference...

Comment: There's not enough information provided to answer your question.

Comment: So i have a python code which takes the input from the user, the user has to enter some values for x one by one, then in the clips part i count y which is the number of odd numbers that he entered, and i want to check if count_x = count_y, but it always prints the Yes even though it shouldn't...